# Qt - Find mouse screen x,y - even application closed

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm new to Qt.  I'd like a window to follow the mouse around the screen.  (It's a useful aid to reading)

The best I can come up with is a timer that uses QPoint QCursor::pos() to move the window every .1 seconds.

Rather than spinning this timer constantly, is there an event system I can tap into?  This would look smoother, and use less computer.

Is there a better way?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

You can override [`QWidget::mouseMoveEvent()`](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) and update your window position there.

Comment: Be sure you enable tracking as well, if it isn't already for your widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try [QTimer](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtimer.html) and its [timeout()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtimer.html#timeout) signal. The event system you're looking for is probably the main event loop, provided by the QCoreApplication or the [QApplication](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qapplication.html) classes.